# How do I store a custom class from within the same assembly in application settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, application-settings

I have a very simple class

```
public class Preferences
{
    public bool RepeatInfinite { get; set; }
    public int RepeatCount { get; set; }
}
```

If I put this class in another assembly it shows up in the Settings tab when you browse for the type.  If I however put this class in the same assembly as the running program, I can't see it or browse for it.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and it's quite annoying.  To work around it I do the following.

- Create the setting and type it to `Object`
- Open the settings file in notepad
- Change the type to the name of the type in the same assembly (fully qualified name)
- Reopen the designer.
- Make an innocuous change, hit save and the C# file gets regenerated with your type.

Comment: Thanks much

I should add the "innocuous change" he speaks out here is to lets say add another setting to the designer & delete it.  Then recompile.  That worked for me at least